What does recurrecence in depth and recurrence in time mean?
I've seen recurrence in depth mentioned in several papers by opposition to recurrence in time (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.04279v1). I am assuming that recurrence in depth means hidden layer to hidden layer - n connections (i.e. a topological property of the NN). Whereas recurrence through time seems to mean that the result of previous full-pass are used to process subsequent ones (i.e. an architecture property). Please correct me.
